# Can more than 10 instances be created in openstack

Tags: openstack, multiple-instances, openstack-horizon

In openstack dashboard in project under compute,limit summary shows instances as 10.
Can we created more than 10 instances.

Answer (score 3):

The limit you see is the quota configured for your project. When the quota is set higher you can create more instances.